# What steps should the add to cart operation go through?

Tags: asp.net-core, e-commerce, shopping-cart, rest, use-case

I am planning to make an e-commerce site and there are some steps that I need to think about.
For example, I will add a product to the cart. In your opinion, what stages should this process go through in the background in order for me to take this action? Which checks should be done in what order? For example, if I assume that I will do stock control, should I do this stock control through a separate stock microservice? Other than that, what kind of steps and checks should it go through?

Here's what I'm planning. I have a frontend application and from here I will send a request to my cart service (a rest api) via an ApiGateway when the user presses the add to cart button. The addbasket method of this service will be run. Here I will first check stock from my stock micro service. If there is stock, I will add it to the cart. If not, I'll be back.

What else should I do here? Also where should I store the basket? Should I consider a database or a different option?

Actually, what I want to ask is what steps should I go through and what controls should I do to develop the add to cart operation. At this stage, where should I store the products in the basket, etc.?

Could you please explain what is the best way to make this work?
thank you everyone

Comment: You need to know the requirements and you need to make the decisions for your architecture. We're not going to do that for you.

Comment: The question is interesting, but necessarily opinion based and probably to broad as well.